# Tool for state machine development and verification

Tags: python, c++, uml

Hy, I'm looking for a tool to build my state machines and verify them. Possible languages for generating the code are Python or C++. I did a bit of research but I just want some input from different sides.

Comment: Are you saying that the tool should generate either Python or C++ (but that you don't care what language it is written in)? You mention UML in the tags, but not the question - should the answer include some UML functionality (if so, which) or not? And could you list what you have already looked at (which will help others) including any reasons why you might not want to use it? Welcome aboard! I look forward to an answer for this great question :-)

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you want but maybe you have to look at yacc / lex (bison / flex).

Comment: The idea is to create a UML state machine diagram and verify the diagram or generate the code from the diagram and then verify.