# State machine code generator

Tags: c++, uml, code-generation

I'm developing a state machine and for that I researched if there are tools which generate code from UML diagram. Does anyone know what kind of tools exists there? I would want a code in C or C++.

Comment: Did you google for e.g "State machine code generator"? I think this would give some starting points.

Comment: As might the OP's [own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53697/tool-for-state-machine-development-and-verification)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of the OP's [own question from '17](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53697/tool-for-state-machine-development-and-verification). That one got  no answer, but the way to attract one is a bounty, not a duplicate question.

Comment: OK one thing is the verification. If somebody has input about code generation tool that work and are not to expensive I'm all ears. Otherwise I'l try to publish tools and what I have on that topic.